# How to properly delete an array of std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, delete-operator

I can create a dynamic 2d-array of 3x2 ints and I can delete it without problems. But when doing the same with a 2d-array of strings, deleting it generates the error:

munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Why? **This lack of homogeneity between ints and strings is preventing me from writing a template** that can be instantiated with strings.

I know there are automatic pointers. I know there are better alternatives to primitive language arrays. But I am a teacher and I am trying to introduce the subjects one by one, so I still cannot use those more advanced topics. I am trying to explain abstract types of data with templates.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "2d-ARRAY of ints" << std::endl;
  int **a = new int*[3];
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    a[i] = new int[2];
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    delete a[i];
  delete [] a;

  std::cout << "2d-ARRAY of strings" << std::endl;
  std::string **s = new std::string*[3];
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    s[i] = new std::string[2];
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    delete s[i];
  delete [] s;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to use delete [] instead of the simple delete. For example delete [] a[i];

Comment: You're a teacher... why are you teaching creating 2D arrays like this? Use std::vectors.

Comment: use `std::array` for fixed size and `std::vector` otherwise, I dont see a reason to enter such difficulties here

Comment: Should be `delete[] a[i]` and `delete[] s[i]`.

Comment: "so I still cannot use those more advanced topic" ... using c-arrays and proper manual memory managment is super advanced. Using `std::vector` is easy.

Comment: I'm doubtful that teaching templates before teaching standard containers is a logical order. You don't need to understand templates to understand `vector`s or how to use them. You only need to understand templates to *implement* them. And standard containers should be one of the early things taught. Probably even before dynamic allocation and C arrays.

Comment: Even if your excuse about being a teacher had any logic, then by that same logic, why is it somehow OK to use `std::string` instead of char arrays? Wouldn't students have a lot more fun and productive times if they were forgetting to free strings and forgetting to add null terminators and using `strtok()` and all that other crappy stuff that C++ should've left behind by now? [rolls eyes]

Comment: *"I still cannot use those more advanced topics"* - Raw pointers for dynamic allocation are the advanced topic. Virtually no one needs to use them for that purpose - it is only really needed for specialized things. Most people only every need `std::array` and `std::vector`.

Comment: There is no lack of homogeneity - your use of `delete` when you should `delete []` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is it deliberately ironic that instead of "more advanced topics", you have decided to teach "basic" yet clearly error-prone memory management that even you can't get right? :)

Comment: Also **please** don't teach this kind of data layout. There is no need for a vector of vectors, or the manual equivalent (which this is). An array of pointers to pointers is almost always wrong. I spend a good chunk of each month here undoing the damage that causes.

Comment: All teaching like this does is to make students leave C++ forever and go onto other languages that they can actually create real programs with.  A new student to C++ is not going to get freaked out by seeing `std::vector<int>` since the new student is new -- they have not been biased by seeing `C` syntax with pointers and believing `int *` "looks easier".

Comment: I recommend watching this advice for teaching C++ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of unsafe (as your program has demonstrated) dynamically "manually" allocated arrays C++ suggests the standard container `std::vector`.

Nevertheless as for your program then you are using an invalid operator delete with dynamically allocated arrays.

Instead of

```
delete a[i];
```

and

```
delete s[i];
```

you have to use

```
delete [] a[i];
```

and

```
delete [] s[i];
```

> But I am a teacher and I am trying to introduce the subjects one by
>   one, so I still cannot use those more advanced topics. I am trying to
>   explain abstract types of data with templates.

I see nothing bad in this approach of teaching. After seeing what difficulties arise using dynamically allocated arrays the students will better understand the advantages of using standard containers.:)

Comment: _"After seeing"_ Therein lies the rub. Will they see it? Would they even have been aware of it had this program not happened to cause a memory fault? :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What about for example exceptions and forgetting to free a memory or changing the initial address of allocated memory?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow To see the complexity, you need something to compare it. Otherwise, it looks like the normal thing to do. This is another reason starting with the easier higher level solutions is better. When they get to manual memory management, it sucks for them and they appreciate the cognitive burden that performing memory management yourself imposes.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I saw two approaches. And even such a construction as std::cout << something; is harder understandable compared with printf.:)